# Is there a way to save custom metadata using pdfjs library

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

Is there a way to save custom metadata using Mozilla pdfjs library?
I was able to retrieve the existing metadata using .getMetadata() function.

```
PDF_DOC.getMetadata().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //Setting new customdata
            data.info.customMetadata= "newdata";
            //save the custom data

        })
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See this one: https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/55

Comment: Only via `pdf.js` or any other library?

Comment: You can do that easily via pdf-lib. Here is working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/Hopding/vcwmfnbe/2/

Comment: has your problem been solved? do you want I post an answer?

Comment: No, I actually want to add a new entity  as custom data.Using pdflib, it is possible to save author,subject,title etc.But I didn't find a way to add an entirely new custom data